# parsing a json in loop where element names change

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, loops, titanium

I'm parsing a JSON response which isn't set up the best, in my opinion. Here is the actual response:

```
[
    {"challenge_id":"39029"},
    {"song1_id":"198","name":"PRAY","url":"https:\/\/s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com\/test\/TAKE_THAT_-_PRAY.mp3"},
    {"song2_id":"251","name":"THE TEARS OF A CLOWN","url":"https:\/\/s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com\/test\/SMOKEY_ROBINSON_-_THE_TEARS_OF_A_CLOWN.mp3"},
    {"song3_id":"11","name":"WONDERFUL TONIGHT","url":"https:\/\/s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com\/test\/ERIC_CLAPTON_-_WONDERFUL_TONIGHT.mp3"},
    {"song4_id":"288","name":"THE NAME OF THE GAME","url":"https:\/\/s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com\/test\/ABBA_-_THE_NAME_OF_THE_GAME.mp3"},
    {"song5_id":"159","name":"I'M EVERY WOMAN","url":"https:\/\/s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com\/test\/CHAKA_KHAN_-_I'M_EVERY_WOMAN.mp3"},
    {"status":"ok"}
]
```

and here was my attempt at parsing it:

```
var challenge_Songs = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

for(var i = 1; i<challenge_Songs.length-1; i++){
    challengeSongs[i-1] = challenge_Songs[i].url;
    challengeTitles[i-1] = challenge_Songs[i].name;
    voteSongIds[i-1]= challenge_Songs.song[i]_id;
}
```

My problem is with obtaining what I have set up as voteSongIds, as the name changes within every iteration of the loop. What I have tried above is causing a run time error. If I comment the line with votesongids, everything works. How should I parse the parse JSON?! Any help appreciated :) I'm using titanium, but for these purposes, it's just javascript!

Comment: An array holding multiple types and an ID field that doesn't have a consistent name, interesting. I'd try and see if there's a chance of receiving sane output instead of trying to work with this abomination.

Comment: I dunno man, not sure if this will work but try this voteSongIds.push(challenge_Songs[i]['song'+ i +'_id'])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this the result you looking for?

```
var challenge_Songs  = [
{"challenge_id":"39029"},
{"song1_id":"198","name":"PRAY","url":"https:\/\/s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com\/test\/TAKE_THAT_-_PRAY.mp3"},
{"song2_id":"251","name":"THE TEARS OF A CLOWN","url":"https:\/\/s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com\/test\/SMOKEY_ROBINSON_-_THE_TEARS_OF_A_CLOWN.mp3"},{"song3_id":"11","name":"WONDERFUL TONIGHT","url":"https:\/\/s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com\/test\/ERIC_CLAPTON_-_WONDERFUL_TONIGHT.mp3"},
{"song4_id":"288","name":"THE NAME OF THE GAME","url":"https:\/\/s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com\/test\/ABBA_-_THE_NAME_OF_THE_GAME.mp3"},
{"song5_id":"159","name":"I'M EVERY WOMAN","url":"https:\/\/s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com\/test\/CHAKA_KHAN_-_I'M_EVERY_WOMAN.mp3"},{"status":"ok"}]

var challengeTitles=[], 
    challengeSongs = [], 
    voteSongIds=[];

for(var i = 1; i < challenge_Songs.length-1; i++){
    challengeTitles.push(challenge_Songs[i]['name']);
    challengeSongs.push(challenge_Songs[i]['url']);
    voteSongIds.push(challenge_Songs[i]['song'+ i +'_id'])
}

console.log(challengeTitles);
console.log(challengeSongs);
console.log(voteSongIds);
```

Comment: Thanks, that sorted it!

Comment: Hi I am having another similar issue which you may be able to help me with, if you have the time, I would be very grateful. I have a question created here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19366024/sending-a-tricky-array-in-a-httpclient

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. This will work perfect whatever the key or value

```
for(var i = 0; i<challenge_Songs.length; i++){
  for(key in challenge_Songs[i]){
   console.log("\n key=>" + key + " : value=> " + challenge_Songs[i][key]);
  }
  console.log("\n");
}
```

It will display you all the keys and correspondent value in more simple way