# sending a tricky array in a httpclient

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, titanium, httpclient

I have to integrate data from an array into a webservice call which isn't the most efficient but it is what it is.

I have an array of ids (friend facebook ids).
I need to send these id's as parameters in a http client in titanium. 
Due to Titanium having some trouble with passing arrays in webservices, I need to construct the send method of my http client as such:

```
non_xhr.send('user_id=100005941351187&friend_ids[0]=100000049956179&friend_ids[1]=100005272411678');
```

Obviousy depending on the user, they will have a different number of results to be stored in the array previously mentioned (of facebook friend ids).

I need help in how to integrate a loop based on the length of array mentioned above in order to construct the parameters needed, as described above.

All help appreciated.

I am using Titanium but for the purposes of this question, it is basically just javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about creating your params like that:

```
function createParams(userId, friendIds) {
    var output = "user_id=" + userId;

    for(var i = 0, max = friendIds.length; i < max; i++) {
        output += "&friend_ids[" + i + "]=" + friendIds[i];
    }

    return output;
}
```

You can find a working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mwfire/bZySK/).